# Image inside div is not floating correctly

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a school project and I have `<div class="pos_cen">` tag. Inside the div are some paragraphs and an image for each one. When I go into my CSS style sheet for the page, everything else is styled BUT the image. I want it to float right but it wont.

I tried doing `img { float: right;}` on my stylesheet but nothing happened.

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: It's possible that the CSS rule you added for the image was overridden by another CSS rule with higher specificity or more specific selectors. Please add more details.

Comment: It is usually fixed by giving display:block to img.
but if not, we can help better if you share the codes.